# nice way of doing 'if ALL items in collection pass test'

Tags: algorithm, language-design

I mean this:

```
bool passed = true;
for(int i = 0; i < collection.Length; i++)
{
    if(!PassesTest(collection[i]))
    {
        passed = false;
        break;
    }
}
if(passed){/*passed code*/}
```

requires extra variable, extra test

```
for(int i = 0; i < collection.Length; i++)
{
    if(!PassesTest(collection[i]))
    {
        return;
    }
}
{/*passed code*/}
```

neat, but requires this to be it's own function, if this it's self is inside a loop or something, not the most performant way of doing things. also, writing a whole extra function is a pain

```
if(passed){/*passed code*/}
for(int i = 0; i < collection.Length; i++)
{
    if(!PassesTest(collection[i]))
    {
        goto failed;
    }
}
{/*passed code*/}
failed: {}
```

great, but  you have to screw around with label names and ugly label syntax

```
for(int i = 0; ; i++)
{
    if(!(i < collection.Length))
    {
         {/*passed code*/}
         break;
    }
    if(!PassesTest(collection[i]))
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

probably the nicest, but still a bit manual, kinda wasting the functionality of the for loop construct, for instance, you can't do this with a foreach

what is the nicest way to handle this problem?

it seems to me something like this would be nice:
foreach(...)
{
    ...
}
finally{...} // only executed if loop ends conventionally (without break)

am I missing something? because this is a very common problem for me, and I don't really like any of the solutions I've come up with.

I use c++ and C#, so solutions in either would be great.
but would also be interested in solutions in other languages. (though a design principle that avoids this in any language would be ideal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your language doesn't have this feature, write a function "forall," which takes two arguments: a list and a boolean-valued function which is to be true for all elements of the list.  Then you only have to write it once, and it matters very little how idiomatic it is.

The "forall" function looks exactly like your second code sample, except that now "collection" and "passesTest" are the arguments to that function.

Calling forall looks roughly like:

```
if (forall(myList,isGood)) {
```

which is readable.

As an added bonus, you could implement "exists" by calling "forall" on the negated boolean function, and negating its answer.  That is, "exists x P(x)" is implemented as "not forall x not P(x)".

Answer (score 2):

You can use Linq in .NET.
Here's an example in C#:

```
if(collection.All(item => PassesTest(item)))
{
    // do my code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ and STL

```
if (std::all_of(collection.begin(), collection.end(), PassesTest))
{
    /* passed code */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby:

```
if collection.all? {|n| n.passes_test?}
  # do something
end
```

Clojure:

```
(if (every? passes-test? collection)
  ; do something
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Groovy:

```
if (!collection.find { !PassesTest(it) }) {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Scala:

```
def passesTest(i: Int) = i < 5 // example, would likely be idiomatically in-line
var seq = List(1,2,3,4);
seq.forall(passesTest) // => True
```

Most, if not all of the answers presented here are saying: **higher-order constructs** -- such as "passing functions" -- **are really, really nice**. If you are designing a language, don't forget about the last 60+ years of programming languages/designs.

Answer (score 0):

Python (since v2.5):

```
if all(PassesTest(c) for c in collection):
    do something
```

Notes:

- we can iterate directly on collection, no need for an index and lookup
- [all() and any() builtin functions](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#other-language-changes) were added in Python 2.5
- the argument to `any()`, i.e. `PassesTest(c) for c in collection`, is a *generator expression*. You could also view it as a *list comprehension* by adding brackets `[(PassesTest(c) for c in collection]`
- `... for c in collection` causes iteration through a collection (or sequence/tuple/list). For a dict, use `dict.keys()`. For other datatypes, use the correct iterator method.